# moving tables between multisite installs

Tags: multisite

So I have a WP multisite install where our client made changes over on a staging site. But now we need to bring the changed tables back in. The issue is we didnt bring the entire DB to staging, and cant bring the entire DB back in. We have 260+ sites and only need to stage the one site and test a few sub sites. So our staging is like a cross section of 15 sites.

I know how to move sub sites with a clear ID (wp_#_) but this is blog ID #1.

So i brought in ALL non site specific wp_ tables but nothing.

So where is blog id #1 data saved if there is no wp_1_ in my 10k table DB?

Comment: For the main site, the tables do not have an integer.  For example: wp_commentmeta, wp_comments, wp_posts, etc,

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought too.

So we made a ton of page edits to site 1, including a theme change. I deleted all wp_ tables on the production site, and copied the same wp_ tables from staging to production, but its like nothing happened. No theme change, same pages, etc. Staging has 106 pages, production only shows 84. I have moved the tables over twice, no luck.

Comment: theme information is stored in wp_options.  I think you might not be transferring over all the tables over for the main site (id=1).

Comment: Yep, I moved ALL wp_ tables with no results. I even see the right template in the wp_options, yet when i visit the site or the admin, its not using that new theme. #stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the client had us working on the wrong database. One with all the same files, but not the one the site was pulling from. Ugh.

Yes, WP_ is the right set of tables to move and all is well when you are on the right DB.

Answer (score 1):

For WP multisite these are the main site (ID=1) database tables:

```
wp_commentmeta
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_posts
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_terms
```

Comment: Yep, I moved ALL wp_ tables with no results.